# ring redirect after login

Tags: redirect, clojure, ring

```
(ns ...
  (:require  [ring.util.response :refer [ response redirect]))
```

My original code be-all-like

```
(-> (response "You are now logged in! communist party time!")
    (assoc :session new-session)
    (assoc :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}))
```

Which worked well, but the user still has to navigate elsewhere manually.

Trying to use http://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.util.response.html#var-redirect

```
(-> (redirect requri)
    (assoc :session new-session)
    (assoc :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}))
```

doesn't do anything (aside from returning a blank page).

How can I achieve a redirect to a known uri using ring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`response` is return a body.
you code is `(response requri)`,but the param of the funtion `reponse` is html body,not a uri,you can use the [this function](http://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.util.response.html#var-redirect)

like this

```
(ns foo
   (:require [ring.util.response :as response]))
(def requi "/")
(-> (response/redirect requri)
    (assoc :session new-session)
    (assoc :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}))
```

ps: if you are writing a web site.the [lib-noir](https://github.com/noir-clojure/lib-noir) is a good way to control the session and other.

Comment: my bad, made a mistake in my original post.  I /do/ have (redirect requri) but it doesn't redirect... just a blank page.  Thanks for your help... Will look at lib-noir more

Comment: many times the `redirect` is be used at the end of function,because is a command，not a page.and i don't know the session where you are store.how to certify the user who is login.

Comment: I looked at lib-noir pages and found https://github.com/noir-clojure/lib-noir/blob/master/src/noir/response.clj (go down to (defn redirect ...)) it showed me that I can just return a response map to the same effect:  {:status 302, :body "", :session new-session, :headers {"Location" requri}} -- works awesome.  thanks for helping =D

Answer (score 2):

ipaomian has the answer.

Wanted to share a nice redirect hack:

```
(ns foo
   (:require [ring.util.response :as response]))

(defn redirect
  "Like ring.util.response/redirect but also accepts key value pairs
   to assoc to response."
  [url & kvs]
  (let [resp (response/redirect url)] 
    (if kvs (apply assoc resp kvs) resp)))

(redirect "/" :session new-session :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"})
```

Comment: Cool!  Could you add some example code and what the output / url bar would look like?

Answer (score 0):

ipaomian is right however mine worked by removing the headers. This is my code:

```
(:require
    [ring.util.response :refer [redirect]])

(defn set-user! [id {session :session}]
  (-> (redirect "/home")
      (assoc :session (assoc session :user id))))
```